# How to make Excel read only

Tags: excel

How do I protect an excel file such that it is read only but if the user saves the file in another name, they can now edit?

I would like the user to preserve the content and structure of the excel sheet but can modify if they save it under a new name.

Comment: You can set the readonly flag for the file in the OS.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of options available in the information pane of the file

[image: fig1]